# How to set urlmanager rule on multilanguage website in yii2?

Tags: internationalization, yii2, url-routing, yii-url-manager

We have multilanguage(ua, ru, en) website. And site language automatically inserts in url before any calling to controller/action.

For example if language is 'ua' than request to site/index will be

```
ourwebsite.com/ua/controller/action
```

not

```
ourwebsite.com/controller/action
```

i18n module is standart yii2 i18n module.

I want to set in urlManager, that if language is 'ua' then you can download file. But if language is 'ru' or 'en' and you go on

```
ourwebsite.com/ru/download
or
ourwebsite.com/en/download
```

then you can't download file.

I tried:

```
'<language:(ua)>/download' => 'site/download'
```

But it doesn't work.

if to set

```
'ua/download' => 'site/download'
```

it will work on

```
ourwebsite.com/ua/ua/download
ourwebsite.com/ru/ua/download
ourwebsite.com/en/ua/download
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extension for that-> [Extension](https://github.com/codemix/yii2-localeurls)

Answer (score 0):

*This type of links with the settings*

```
enablePrettyUrl = true; 
showScriptName = false;
```

Comment: These settings were already like this.
I want to download file only if language is 'ua'.

Comment: backend\config\main.php
    'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'app*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@common/messages',
                'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'app' => 'app.php',
                    'app/error' => 'error.php',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
'language' => 'fr',